# Repeating Background Image Stopping at Viewport: Need 100%

Tags: css, image, background, repeat

I have a small .png file that repeats to form a background image. I need to set the `body` height of my page to 100% in order to use min-height property on my content wrapper. However, trying to use the background-image in conjunction with `height:100%` results in the image getting cut off when the page is scrolled. See picture to elaborate what I mean:

Background on top
[image]
But when scrolling it is cut off

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nick_B/x2h3g/

How do I get the background image to repeat over the whole page, even after the user scrolls down? Here is the css:

```
body {  
    background-color:#9AAEBF; 
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:100%;
}

html:after { /* from  www.css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images */
    background-image: url('http://www.example.com/img/background.png');    
    opacity:0.4;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: you could try `position: fixed`, but then you wouldn't have a scroll effect. would that work for you?

Comment: and what's wrong with using the background-image on the `body`? http://jsfiddle.net/x2h3g/4/

Comment: Thanks for your idea @Horen, but need to use `body:after` or `html:after` in order to apply opacity only to background element without affecting child elements. See www.css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images to get an idea of what I am trying to achieve. Thanks for any further ideas.

Comment: there is nothing behind your background-image. so why don't you just open your image in photoshop or gimp, adjust the opacity to your liking and save the picture. much easier and will work in every browser without tweaks.